# Template.FindName returns null

Tags: c#, wpf

`Template.FindName` returns `null` for some reason, the name of my combobox is MsgName and the code is as following:

```
                 ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender;
                 var textbox = (TextBox)box.Template.FindName("MsgName", box);
                 if (textbox != null && _firstKey)
                        {
                            textbox.Select(textbox.SelectionLength, 0);
                            _firstKey = false;
                        }
```

I think there is a mistake in the parameters but I don't know what it is?
This code prevents the ComboBox from highlighting the first character by setting the `SelectionLength` to 0.

Comment: `MsgName` must be the `x:Name` of a TextBox in the template, not the name of the ComboBox.

Comment: okay,  I created a textbook and referenced it but how the code is gonna know which combo-box I want without the reference ?

Comment: What? You pass the ComboBox as reference `box` to the FindName method. When the Template of the ComboBox contains a TextBox with `x:Name="MsgName"`, FindName should return it.

Comment: Is it right to assume that the textbox "MsgName" is part of a data template?